# How to Load Larger Size PDFs in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5, ios4

I wann show PDFs(Books) in my application, i am getting path for the PDF and i m opening it in the WEBVIEW, it works perfectly for the SMALL PDFs but not working for LARGER PDFs.

Whenever I am passing URL of any LARGER SIZE PDF the UI gets frozzen.

can u pls suggest me the better way to do it, so that I can show that PDF whithout taking much time.

> Here is the code that I am using >>

```
 pdfURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"URL GOES HERE"];
[webViewForPDF loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:pdfURL]];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say 'UI gets frozen' does it load the PDF after a while? This freezing of the UI could be that the WebView is loading the PDF, if this is a large PDF it could take some time.

Comment: @rckoenes No, it does not load the Larger pdf, I keep waiting for nearly 40-45 min.

Comment: Did you set the [`delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) of the WebView. This will allow you to catch some callbacks from the webviews. including any load errors

Comment: @rckoenes Yes I did this already. I am using XIB.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is located or downloaded into the local file system, you might also want to look at using UIDocumentInteractionController to open and view the said file. Read all about it here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304

Answer (score 0):

In API documentation there is a way to load a PDF (with Quartz): CGPDFDocument is the object you need and CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL is probably the constructor you are looking for.

Here are some examples on how to do it: [here](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF109)

Take a look at [this](http://iosguy.com/2010/09/04/presenting-pdf-files-by-yourself/) link

Comment: Thanks for the quick responce, I am going through the documentation.